# Convert split('[-/.]') to preg_split() equivalent

Tags: php, regex

I've seen a couple of articles on converting the old `split()` into `preg_split()`, but none with the `/` delimiter thus far.

How would I go about converting `split('[-/.]')` into the `preg_split()` equivalent? My regex knowledge is terrible!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5):

```
preg_split('~[-/.]~', ...
```

Delimiter can be almost any character

If you explicitly want it to be a slash - escape all slashes in your expression

```
preg_split('/[-\/.]/', ...
```

Comment: Oh I see, I though the delimiter HAD to be a `/`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
preg_split('#[-/.]#',"your_text")
```